# Hide Elements So they will no Post Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with several tables with many input fields in each.

Above each Table I have an `<h2>` where I do this:

```
$retVal .= "<h2><input value='{$category}' type='checkbox' name='Categories[]' onclick='CheckboxCategory($category);'  checked='checked' />&nbsp;" . $MSCategories[$i] ."</h2>";

// below this is table
$retVal .= "<table id=\"tableId{$category}\" class=\"search_table\" style='border-spacing: 0px;'>\n";
// edited out 
$retVal .= "</table>";
```

The idea is, if they check this box (in `<h2>`), it runs this script:

```
function CheckboxCategory(catUniqueKey) {
    // jQuery
    if ($("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).is(":visible")) {
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).hide();
    } else {
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).show();
    }
}
```

I want to hide this specific table so that it doesn't post any values from it (rather than user going down and unchecking a few dozen boxes).  This top checkbox I'd like to take care of that.

But apparently, if a checkbox is checked, when the table is hidden, it still posts that value.

Is there something else I can do besides `hide` that actually removes any traces of this part of the form?

Comment: `disabled = disabled` on an input element will prevent it from posting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you hide *and* disable the input item, it will not post.

Comment: I'd clone the table and put it in an hidden div outside the form then remove the table from the form.

Comment: Hiding will have no effect.

Comment: Hiding an element does not remove it from the DOM. It still exists as a part of the form, and will post. You need to remove the unneeded elements with something like .detach() and store them in a js var if you need to re-insert them. or as travis said use disabled

Comment: Ok, I guess disabling it is the answer.  No one line of code can do that really.. oh well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hidden` elements will be posted to the server but the `disabled` will not be posted so you have to disable the elements

try this

```
function CheckboxCategory(catUniqueKey) {
    // jQuery
    if ($("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).is(":visible")) {
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).hide();
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).prop('disabled',true);
    } else {
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).show();
        $("#tableId" + catUniqueKey).prop('disabled',false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you disablethe element  along side with hiding  it will do it.